# Vue Bootstrap Form Datepicker b-form-datepicker modal occurence

Tags: vuejs2, datepicker, styling, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-vue

I am using the calendar component from https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker.

I want to achive these two issues:

1. When the calendar modal is shown I want the other background to be darkenend/faded out. That way the user easier gains the mental focus to the widget and the date to be selected.
   How to achive that?
2. It would also be nice to have the calendar, when displayed, to be shown in the middle of the page. Just like a modal menu.
   How to achive that?
3. I cannot really get an understanding of the documentation's **Dark mode** https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker#dark-mode.
   Where and how to "*Set the **dark** prop to **true** to enable the dark background.*"?
   This could sound like solving my first question...

Thanks for any hints on solving that...

Comment: I did figure out my 3. item. The b-form-datepicker just shows an attribute 'dark' without any value associated. That would be equal to dark prop to true. The effect is that only the calendar gui element shows a dark background. So this does not solve my question shown on the 1. item.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to not use `b-form-datepicker` and instead use `b-calendar`, which allows you to place the date selection window where you want.

In this case, we can use `b-modal` which has the functionality of being centered on the screen, and having a backdrop by default without any extra work.

This also allows you to customize the "input" part of the date-picker to whatever you want, since it's not directly attached to the calendar.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: null,
      modalId: 'date-picker-modal',
      dateContext: {}
    }
  },
  watch: {
    /* Close the modal when the date changes */
    value(newVal, oldVal) {
      if(newVal !== oldVal) {
        this.$bvModal.hide(this.modalId)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-4">
  <!-- Try to imitate the default datepicker look -->
  <b-input-group v-b-modal="modalId">
    <template #prepend>
      <b-button variant="transparent" class="border border-right-0">
        <b-icon icon="calendar"></b-icon>
      </b-button>
    </template>
    <label class="form-control border-left-0 cursor-pointer">
      {{ dateContext.selectedFormatted }}
    </label>
  </b-input-group>
  
  <b-modal :id="modalId" centered hide-header hide-footer no-fade static content-class="w-auto mx-auto">
    <b-calendar v-model="value" @context="ctx => dateContext = ctx"></b-calendar>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks good. I gave iut a fast try. I could not to get it closed on date selection but I will investigate... Thank you very much.